# Linux zip doesn't maintain directory structure

Tags: linux, directory, zip

I have a directory I am trying to zip on Linux before sending it to Windows.

I thought it worked with this command:

```
zip -r directory.zip directory
```

However when I looked at the directory it contained only the files, no folders. 
It's as if the -j command is the default, which is confusing.

I looked in the manual and I could not see any means of forcing it to maintain the directory structure in the zip.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was an unzipping issue, not a zipping issue. 
The unzip command required -d to maintain the directory structure.

```
wzunzip -d directory.zip
```